# How to import mp3 files with next.js?

Tags: reactjs, audio, next.js, mp3

I'm trying to import mp3 files to my next.js project - [image]

I want to access the file 'DRUMS.mp3' from AudioPlayer.js so I wrote

`import drums from '../resources/DRUMS.mp3';`

but this comes up:

[image]

I've also installed - 'npm install file-loader --save-dev'
but that didn't help.

Thanks to all responders!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use an html `audio` tag to play it - place it in the public folder and then reference them directly, i.e

```
 <audio
        controls
        src="/DRUMS.mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
```

If you want to further interact with the audio api, you could use the `webaudio` API - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: It still says that it can't find the file DRUMS.mp3..
I tried also - src="../resources/DRUMS.mp3"

Comment: is resources under `public` directory?

Comment: no, should it be?

Comment: yes put it inside `public` so `public/resources` and then refer as `/resources/DRUMS.mp3`